# What imputation method should I use for item-level missingness in the MICE package, using the mice() function?

Tags: missing-data, mice

I have a parenting questionnaire with three sub-scales. Within the sub-scales I have item level missing data. It is less than 5% of the data, but I would like to use multiple imputation to correct the missing data. I am using the MICE package in R, and the mice() function. I wanted to ask what method of imputation should I use? I know the package has built in imputation methods (e.g., pmm or norm), but I wasn't sure which imputation method was appropriate for item level missingness? Or how I should choose between the multiple options? I know that I do not what to use any of the two-level imputation methods, as they do not apply. But beyond that I am at a loss for how to choose between the multiple imputation methods that the package offers. For any of you who have experience with R or the MICE package, any and all feedback would be greatly appreciated! Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: What do you mean "item level missingness"? The variable is missing for everyone?

Comment: Please put some links in to various terms, the terms you are using are so specific to R that it limits the potential readership.

Answer (score 1):

The two methods you mention (predictive mean matching, and normal) are suitable for imputing continuous variables. Your reference to items in a sub-scale leads me to believe that these have only two or a small number of categorical values. In that case you would choose a different method logistic regression for binary and proportional odds for ordered categorical. My feeling is that with less than 5% missing the results are unlikely to be affected much but it is worth doing as a sensitivity analysis.